Почему в telebot next_step_handler не перехидт к следующей функции
У меня есть блоки которые должны записывать данные в базу данных через next_step_handler но по какой то причине после выполнения функции step_1_for_new_product и после введения цены пользователем далее уже ничего не происходит, по факту step_2_for_new_product даже не запускается, в чем может быть проблема?
main.py:
    elif call.data == 'add_products':
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Напишите название Продукта:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, lambda message: step_1_for_new_product(message))

func.py:
def step_1_for_new_product(message):
    product = message.text
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Products (product_name) VALUES (?)", (product,))
    connection.commit()
    product_id = cursor.lastrowid
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите цену товара:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lambda message: 
step_2_for_new_product(message, product_id))


def step_2_for_new_product(message, product_id):
    categories = get_all_categories()
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    for category_id, name in categories:
        markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name, 
callback_data=f"category_{category_id}"))

    product = int(message.text)
    changeinfo_products(product_id, "product_price", product)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите категорию товаров:", 
reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lambda message: 
   step_3_for_new_product(message, product_id, category_id))


def step_3_for_new_product(message, product_id, category_id):
    apply_markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    yes = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Подтвердить", 
callback_data=f"yes_{product_id}")
    no = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Отмена", callback_data=f"no_{product_id}")
    apply_markup.add(yes, no)
    changeinfo_products(product_id, "category", category_id)
    product_name = send_info_products(product_id, "product_name")
    product_price = send_info_products(product_id, "product_price")
    category = send_info_categories(category_id, "category_name")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Подтвердите/Отклоните создание 
товара\n\nНазвание товара: {product_name}\n"
                                  f"Цена Товара: {product_price}\nКатегория Товара: {category}",
                 reply_markup=apply_markup)
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lambda message: step_3_for_new_product(message))


Непонятно, что у вас не работает. Я несколько раз попробовал воспроизвести проблему, но ничего подобного не увидел.
